# How to flip list to dictionary python

Tags: python

can you help me to flip list to dictionary

> shopping_list = raw_input("Enter you Shopping List: ").title().split(',')

i need to flip this list to dictionary
and i dont know how much product the user want to input

Comment: dictionary has keys and values. What would be the keys & values in your case?

Comment: What does the user's input string look like?

Comment: Check out `dict.fromkeys()`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: not sure how you'd make a dictionary out of a list of items.  the input for a shopping list would be something like ('apples','oranges','grapes')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit ambiguous as you did not provide example input or output. I will assume that you are going to ask the user multiple times to enter in an item and how many they need separated by a comma. If the input changes, then I will edit my answer.

```
dictionary = {}
item, numberOfItems = raw_input("Enter your Shopping List: ").title().split(',')
dictionary[item] = numberOfItems
```

This is assuming that no matter what, your input comes in the form of:

```
banana,3
carrot,7
pack of gum,9
```

**Edit**
Since I see what the input is, I can answer this better.

The input string someone will input follows this pattern:

```
item1,3,item2,7,item3,20,item4,5
```

So we need to split the input every 2 items.

```
my_list = raw_input("Enter your Shopping List: ").title().split(',')
composite_list = [my_list[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(my_list),2)]
```

This should set `composite_list` as such.

```
[[item1,3], [item2,7], [item3,20], [item4,5]]
```

Now all we need to do is loop through `composite_list`

```
for pair in composite_list:
    print('({}:{})'.format(pair[0], pair[1]))
```

The output will now look like:

```
(item1:3)
```

Comment: And how can i to print the item with his number of items

Comment: I honestly dont know exactly what you are asking. Can you provide me some examples of your input and output that you are expecting?

Comment: If my input its banana,3,carrot,7 How can i print (banana:3)(carrot:7)